# Folder structure for React and Django REST

Tags: django, reactjs, directory

I'm in the process of refactoring a rather basic/traditional Django webapp to a more modern React-plus-Django-REST setup. I'm far more familiar with Django than React, so where to put the React part is what's confusing to me.

My question is: what are the best practices for folder structure in using both Django and React? Ideas I've had:

1. Put all React files in their own folder like this:

   `.
   ├── app1
   │   └── example-files.py
   ├── app2
   │   └── example-files.py
   ├── manage.py
   ├── react-django-project
   │   ├── settings.py
   │   └── urls.py
   ├── requirements.txt
   ├── some-app-1
   │   └── example-files.py
   ├── some-app-2
   │   └── example-files.py
   ├── src
   │   └── components
   │       ├── component1.js
   │       └── component2.js
   └── ...`
2. Put all React files in the static folder, but this doesn't seem right to me.

Is there an established set of best practices for this?

Comment: Most of the time there are two separate projects for the back and the front end. When you run into CORS errors, set up proxy for your react dev server: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy

Comment: Thanks, Igonato. Do you know of an example on github (or elsewhere) where I could see how that's set up?

Comment: It was getting a bit too big for a comment. I posted some useful links as an answer

Comment: It is right actually. React is a client-side library.  So keeping client-side files under `static` folder is fine. You can create a structure like `/static/js/components/` and put all files in it. If you have multiple apps, just add another `apps` folder under `components` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time there are two separate projects for the back and the front end:

To build a ReST API using Django I'd strongly recommend you to check out [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) if you haven't already. There is a simple tutorial on that home page that should get you up and running.

For the React app ["React Create App"](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) seems to be the standard way to start a project nowadays. See the linked GitHub page for step-by-step instructions.

Then follow this ["Proxying API Requests in Development"](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development) guide to proxy requests to your API for your development setup.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Igonato about having separate projects for frontend and backend. As client(Frontend) would make Ajax(API) calls to the server(Backend) and with the response data, client renders the page.

Especially with react, you need to convert the react code to minified js and css for higher performance on the production server.

You may use djangorestframework in the backend and setup a django server. For frontend, here are a couple of options:
 1. you can use [dva](https://github.com/dvajs/dva) (if you intend to use redux). dva is good. I would recommend not to use redux until the state management in your application gets complicated.
 2. If you are not gonna use redux, then you can use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

For front-end I would recommend to use [antd](https://ant.design/) if you want to go for material design based application. It's quite a lot of UI elements that you would need in your application. It's battle tested. I have used it in ~9 applications, I have made in the past 6 months.

Answer (score 2):

As the others mentioned, using different repositories is the common approach to solve this. However for a smaller team / smaller project a single repository should suffice.

To keep everything in one repo you create a separate for folder for the react app, usually I name it `projectname-client`. If you are using `create-react-app` you could serve the `index.html` from the `build` folder by adding that path to settings file.

```
# settings.py
# Path to the frontend app build directory
BUILD_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '{{ project_name }}-client/build')
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BUILD_DIR
        ],
        ...
    },
]
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BUILD_DIR, 'static'),
]

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
]
```

If you are interested, I'm working on a `django-admin startproject` template that sets up the project to work with `create-react-app`. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/bpsagar/django-react-template).